# Meaning of comment at end of page

Tags: discussion

I just got a notice of activity on a question of mine that's been closed. At the bottom of the page, I see this:

`// TODO sg: TMP solution until we are confident in our current implementation of async imports // once we are, we can move the if into the js entry file and dynamically load the mark obsolete module`

Is  this a mistake and something I'm supposed to see, like another comment, or is it a note for the SE developers to fix something?

Edit: Seen on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250656/can-i-increase-the-bevel-depth-on-one-face-but-not-on-the-other).

Edit 2: Wow - this is getting really meta! It was at the bottom of the page for this question after I added the above edit, then was adding a comment. See this:
[image]

Comment: What question was this notice posted to? Never encountered, it, sounds like some sort of debug info a normal user should never see. Should probably be reported to site admins

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: My bad. I should have included the link. I've added it. Also, after I edited this question to add that, as I'm typing this comment, I see it here, too. I'll add a screenshot including it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos: Screenshot showing it on this page, while I was making my last comment is now added. I still see it.

Comment: Seems to be visible only to you, I don't see it on my end. I have reported it to the community manager, if there is anything that can be done about it I'm sure they will eventually take care of it. Thanks for reporting

Comment: If it helps, I'm using Chrome on macOS. I don't see it now. Maybe it's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it was an issue that affected multiple sites. Details are on [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375317/todo-sg-tmp-solution-until-we-are-confident-showing-up-on-question-page).

According to [Adam Lears' response,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375324/387343) this has since been fixed.

> This is part of our new tradition here at Stack Overflow... Whoops
> Wednesday.
>
> Thanks for the report! The fix is out now.

Comment: Thanks. Thought it was an error, but wasn't sure where to report it, thought I'd start where I saw it and figured admins or other wise folk would know where to forward the report. If they know about it, that's all I can do, but I'm glad it's fixed.